# Convert all json rows in a table into a single json array - Postgres

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a table where each row has a json column named data_object. I want to get the data_object for each row and create a json array that represents all rows in the table.

Example:

```
id | data_object
----------------
1  | { "someKey": "someValue", etc. }
2  | { "someKey": "someOtherValue", etc. }
```

Desired Result:

```
[
  { "someKey": "someValue", etc. },
  { "someKey": "someOtherValue", etc. }
]
```

Some of the keys per row are known (a standard set), but some of the the keys per row will vary, I just want a json array that represents all rows in the table for the data_object json column.

I appreciate your help in advance!

Comment: [`json[b]_agg`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html) is your friend

Answer (score 0):

> You can use

```
select array_agg(data_object) from table_name;
```

Comment: That will return an array of json, not a json array.

Comment: Your answer *almost* worked, but this is what seems to do the trick:
select  array_to_json(array_agg(data_object)) from invoice

Answer (score 0):

`jsonb_agg` is what you're looking for:

```
SELECT jsonb_agg(data_object) FROM mytable
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=8b11ef2ee137e764206bd9fd44f97211)